# Azure DevOps NuGet Package not found

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I have added some CI tasks to our Git Repo in Azure DevOps and I'm trying to streamline the NuGet package creation process and then upload it to our Artifact Feed.  The build works well and the logs show that the package was built and put in a directory, but when the Release runs, it says the package can't be found and fails.  Does anyone have experience with streamlining NuGet package creation in Azure DevOps?  Here's a screenshot of the log showing package success:

[image: Build Task]

But when they release pipeline runs, I get this:
[image]

Help!  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the release reference the build as an artifact source, or your NuGet feed? If it references the build, then you have to publish build artifacts using the *Publish Build Artifacts* task. If you're publishing your NuGet package to a package management feed, then you should use that as your artifact source for your release.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please copy the text from the log rather than taking a screenshot. I found this by chance, but had I been able to find it via the error message, I would have found it much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the release references a build, then you have to publish build artifacts using the Publish Build Artifacts task.

If you're publishing your NuGet package to a package management feed, then you should use that as your artifact source for your release.